# AFNetworking ASPXAUTH Cookies AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to work with a .NET server that is returning a ASPXAUTH cookie when logging in. I am definitely getting the cookie back when I watch my network traffic with Charles, but when I inspect `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]` I am not finding it contains anything. Listed is my code below. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc]
                                          initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.com/api/"]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"UserName":@"SomeUserName", @"Password":@"SomePassword"};

[manager POST:@"User/Login" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

}  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: have you solve this issue? how to store cookies

Comment: I just posted the solution I found which works... if you find the answer works for you please vote it up. Thanks!

Comment: Please check also my latest question on stack and answer on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078151/can-afnetworking-2-store-the-cookies

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as... taking the cookie and setting the http header value like so...

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".ASPXAUTH=%@", cookie[@"Value"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

.NET expects the cookie returned in the above format. Hope this helps anyone.